# hosted rest load testing solution

Tags: rest, load-testing, hosted

can anyone recommend a hosted solution for load testing a rest interface (including all verbs, signed requests and multiple sets of simulated tasks)?

we don't want to set up a server with the tools and we only need this occasionally.

we'd like to test it at about 500 requests per second and see how the system responds.

would be awsome if anyone could share their experience with hosted solutions providing this service.

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not a hosted solution but a quick and easy way to load test a HTTP endpoint is to use Fiddler and a plugin called Stress Stimulus http://stresstimulus.stimulustechnology.com/  It's free too!

Comment: i would like to avoid using a computer connected to a dsl line to test that because i am afraid the throughput wouldn't be enough from my local machine. and i don't want to set up any extra server(s) as well. thanks for the quick response though.